# Why delegate event is not received swift?

Tags: swift, delegation

I would like to pass data from `EditPostViewController` to `NewsfeedTableViewController` using delegates, but `func remove(mediaItem:_)` is never called in the adopting `class NewsfeedTableViewController`. What am I doing wrong?

```
  NewsfeedTableViewController: UITableViewController, EditPostViewControllerDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   //set ourselves as the delegate
   let editPostVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditPostViewController") as! EditPostViewController
    editPostVC.delegate = self
 }

  //remove the row so that we can load a new one with the updated data
      func remove(mediaItem: Media) {
        print("media is received heeeee")
        // it does't print anything
    }
}


   extension NewsfeedTableViewController {

//when edit button is touched, send the corresponding Media to EditPostViewController
     func editPost(cell: MediaTableViewCell) {

    let editPostVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditPostViewController") as? EditPostViewController
     guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
        print("indexpath was not received")
        return}

     editPostVC?.currentUser = currentUser
     editPostVC?.mediaReceived = cell.mediaObject
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editPostVC!, animated: true)
 }




 protocol EditPostViewControllerDelegate: class {
   func remove(mediaItem: Media)
 }

 class EditPostViewController: UITableViewController {

  weak var delegate: EditPostViewControllerDelegate?

   @IBAction func uploadDidTap(_ sender: Any) {

    let mediaReceived = Media() 
    delegate?.remove(mediaItem: mediaReceived)
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing anything with editPostVC?  You create it from a storyboard but then never add it to anything.  So it’s not currently on a view hierarchy to receive a tap. ( unless you kept that code out of this example)

Comment: `NewsfeedTableViewController` presents some posts. On newsfeed there is a button `edit` which instantiates editPostVC on click even tap. editPostVC is on the view hierarchy when it has to pass data back to newfeed. I've just updated my question to show how editPostVC is instantiated from newsfeed

Comment: Ok so add the line that makes editPost.delegate = self to the block of code that instaniates editPostVC because each time you call editPost it’s not added to the new instance

Comment: It works. Now I understand it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects instantiating in viewDidLoad(:) and on edit button click event are not the same objects. Make a variable

```
var editPostVC: EditPostViewController?
```

instantiate in in viewDidLoad(:) with delegate

```
editPostVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditPostViewController") as! EditPostViewController
editPostVC.delegate = self
```

and then present it on click event

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(editPostVC, animated: true)
```

or

```
present(editPostVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

you can pass data from presenter to presented VC before or after presenting the VC.

```
editPostVC.data = self.data
```

Comment: It needs to be instantiated every time in func editPost(cell: MediaTableViewCell) {}, otherwise it is not passing the data to the presented view controller, namely editPostVC

Comment: Of course you can pass the data without instantiating it all over again. You have the object reference of the view controller. Just set the data in the editPost(cell: MediaTableViewCell) method before or after the present() method call or navigationController?.pushViewController() call. e.g:

Comment: ```func editPost(cell: MediaTableViewCell) {  // place your code  present(editPostVC, animated: true, completion: nil)  editPostVC.data = self.data  // set the data  }``` @bibscy

Answer (score 1):

I suggest having a property in `NewsfeedTableViewController`

`var editPostViewController: EditPostViewController?`

and then assigning to that when you instantiate the `EditPostViewController`.

The idea is that it stops the class being autoreleased when `NewsfeedTableViewController.viewDidLoad` returns.